# Generic Confirmation Window

Tags: jsf, resourcebundle

Good afternoon in my timezone

I already saw a very similar post in this forum, but i have one more question regarding this theme.
I am implementing a generic confirmation window in the application, this generic confirmation window could be used by any bean in the application.
i have made something like this :

```
<ui:fragment rendered="param['confirmationWindow']">
...
</ui:fragment>
```

(This fragment is placed inside the masterTemplate.xhtml)

and each bean that wants to use this confirmation just have to insert in the request object the "confirmationWindow" like that

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestMap().put("confirmationWindow", true);
```

My question is , how can i dynamically display a differente message inside the window ?Which object should i use to insert the different messages? What is the best approach ?

Thanks in advance

Best regards

Comment: I have an idea but i am not sure of its correctness, i think that you can make an application scope bean and create a variable which can be used in any bean and can be change in any scenario as you want.

Comment: Have you considered using a primefaces confirm Dialog, before reinventing the wheel? http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/overlay/confirmDialog.xhtml